# How can I create a disjunction in NHibernate between three tabels

Tags: nhibernate, criteria

How can I create a disjunction in NHibernate that would accomplish the following,

The legacy database that I am working with have one main tabel and three mapped one-to-one tabels with some similar columns and I want to find it in every singel one of them,

I have tried this, but ofcourse it it isn't working;

```
    public void AddSomeQuery(DetachedCriteria query)
    {
        if (someValue != null)
        {
            query
                .CreateCriteria("tabel1")
                .CreateCriteria("tabel2")
                .CreateCriteria("tabel3")
                    .Add(Restrictions.Eq("ColumnThatEveryTabelHas", someValue));
        }
    }
```

I hope this question is clear enough.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Well I think your question is not too clear. But here is my try:
Why not querying the 3 tables separately and adding together the 3 separate list of values ?